# FormData is missing values from controlled form components

Tags: reactjs, controlled-component

Consider this example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-tom-sskdgp?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)):

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  return (
    <form method="post" action="/example">
      <input type="text" name="first-name" />
      <input type="text" name="last-name" />
      <input
        type="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setEmail(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

If you type in "foo" for the first name, "bar" for the last name, and "baz@example.com" for the email, the payload that is submitted to the server is `first-name=foo&last-name=bar`, not `first-name=foo&last-name=bar&email=baz@example.com`. This is because email is a controlled component whereas the other two are uncontrolled.

The most obvious thing to do would be to refactor the form to use all controlled components, but I'm looking for a way that would be easier and less time consuming.

Comment: There's nothing specific about a form that enforces all components are only controlled or uncontrolled. Maybe include some code to help make your question more clear?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like I just forgot the `name` attribute!

```
<input
  type="email"
  name="email"
  value={email}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  }}
/>
```

With the above, the payload that is submitted to the server is like so, as expected:

```
first-name=foo&last-name=bar&email=baz%40example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to hijack the `onSubmit` event like this ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-mopsa-86254x?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)):

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const firstName = e.target.querySelector("[name=first-name]").value;
    const lastName = e.target.querySelector("[name=last-name]").value;
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("firstName", firstName);
    formData.append("lastName", lastName);
    formData.append("email", email);

    console.log(formData);
    // FormData(3) { firstName → "foo", lastName → "bar", email → "baz@example.com" }

    const response = await fetch('/example', {
      method: 'post',
      body: formData,
    });
    // handle response
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="first-name" />
      <input type="text" name="last-name" />
      <input
        type="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setEmail(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

At a high level, the idea is to:

1. Construct the `FormData` that otherwise would have been sent to the server.
2. Add the data from the controlled component to the `FormData`.
3. Submit to the server.

It's not quite plug-n-play, but at least you don't have to spend the time making the existing uncontrolled components controlled. (1) is probably the most cumbersome, but it doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: @AdamZerner Thanks for the updates! I think the best course of action is to delete the question - I deliberately did not upvote your other answer so that you can delete. I voted to close as a typo though :-)

Comment: @Bergi Sure thing! To me it seems worth leaving the question open though in case anyone else stumbles across this sort of issue. (I wouldn't expect experienced developers to have this question but I could see inexperienced ones having it.)

Comment: If you want the question to be useful to others, you should edit it so that it demonstrates the actual issue in the question. And maybe rename it to something like "Formdata is missing values from controlled from components"

Comment: @Bergi Good idea. Updated.